# Openbravo: generate url to the components

Tags: url, web, web-component, openbravo

I installed ERP "Openbravo" following the [custom](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Custom) approach:

So I followed the steps from the tutorial.I set "localhost" for the parameter "Web URL" in the configuration file. After that I ran the servers, Apache and Tomcat.

When accessing the application via browser using http://localhost/openbravo
The problem I am facing is that,the browser doesn't find some components.

I got this log in console of Google-chrome like this:

```
Login_F1.html:11 GET http://localhost/openbravo/security/localhost/js/ajax.js 404 (Not Found)
```

When i try to accede to  the previous url in a new tab i got "not found",
but when i change  by this URL `"http://localhost/openbravo/web/js/utils.js"` works well.

My question is that how i can make Openbravo generate `"/web/"` instead `"/security/localhost/"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you look at Openbravo.properties file
.....

//Static content URL. Use the default value to make it dynamic.
//Don't change this unless you know what you are doing
web.url=@actual_url_context@/web

// Full URL of the context, *only* used by the Web Services installation 
 and diagnostic task
context.url=http://localhost:8080/openbravo
.....

@actual_url_context@ will get replaced by domain name with port number and application context name (for example: mydomain:8989/openbravo)

404 is due to application is not able to locate ajax.js under 

../web/ajax.js

1 ==> To fix the issue you can just restore to @actual_url_context@ and perform smartbuild.

or do an install.source

2 ==> To add any client side customization or to support static content under web folder you can follow
an example: http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_add_a_button_to_the_toolbar
http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_create_a_Manual_UI_Process
```